# How to delete an element of array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, for-loop

My function should delete an element in an array, but when I run my program (there is no mistake), clicking the button does nothing.

Here is my function:

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim delete As Integer = TextBox2.Text

    For i As Integer = 0 To niz.Length - 1
        If niz(i) = delete Then
            niz(i) = niz(niz.Length - n + 1)
            n -= 1
        End If
    Next

    ReDim niz(n - 1)
End Sub
```

If you don´t understand what I wrote can you please send me some code that deletes an element in an array in general?

Comment: Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim delete As Integer = TextBox2.Text
        For i As Integer = 0 To niz.Length - 1
            If niz(i) = delete Then
                niz(i) = niz(niz.Length - n + 1)
                n -= 1
            End If
        Next
        ReDim niz(n - 1)
    End Sub

Comment: Please enable [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) for this project (and set it as the default for new projects). It will point out some mistakes and offer fixes for you to consider.

Comment: It looks like you want to use the [List<T> Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) instead of an array. It has a variety of methods to remove items.

Comment: If you don't use PRESERVE with your ReDim statement, you're going to lose all your existing data.

Comment: As written, you're taking the next higher element, copying it over the deleted element, and then removing the last element from the array (notwithstanding the omitted `Preserve`).  You need to think about copying *every* higher element one step down, not just the next higher element.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what is "n" to me. It's never assigned. But yeah I would do it like this:

```
    Dim nizList = niz.ToList

    For Each element In nizList
        If element = delete Then
            nizList.Remove(element)
        End If
    Next
    niz = nizList.ToArray
```